# Coloring a table in apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

I want to color the background bars (or the entire cells) of the table as shown in the appended screenshot based on the "Group-By"/dimension value (red for "rot", yellow for "gelb" and green for "grün").

I was able to color the metric-part of other visualizations with label_colors, but I have not yet found a way to color the cells of the table based on a "dimension".

Is there a way to do this?
As of now:
[image]

EDIT: I wanted to color it the following way (edited with paint):
[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is apparently not possible. The gitHub project also seems pretty dead as far as I can tell - all improvement requests are on hold for quite some time which is a shame.

Comment: do you have a working copy that we can use to debug? any code to work from?

Comment: I don't think it's actually a bug - I think the functionality is simply missing when it comes to tables.

Comment: This is not possible in Superset 2.1.0, though basic conditional formatting based on numeric value [got added in 2021](https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/15651).

The GitHub project is very alive, with multiple PRs merged / issues opened & closed daily.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tad hacky, but you can add a markdown component and add the following markup:

```
 <style>
   th {
      color: red; /* or whatever color/hex code you want */
   }
</style>
```

The markdown component will be blank after you add this--i.e. there will just be a blank markdown block-- so you may want to add some copy. Alternatively, if you already have a markdown block, you can add it there, and it won't appear as long as you remember the `<style></style>` tags.

Comment: This would simply change the color of the text which is not the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I misinterpreted the screenshot. So the question is, can you dynamically change the color of the table cell text depending on what content of the cell is? Not sure I'm interpreting it correctly but not enough reputation to ask above :-(

Comment: I didn't want to color the text, but the metric *bars* (the bars of the numbers 115, 52, 13) based on the dimension value.

Comment: Ah, gotcha--so CSS won't be the solution anyway, since you need it to be dynamic.